# Storing raster imagery in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgis, raster, postgresql, geotiff-tiff, postgis-raster

I have a number of raster files saved locally which I use for basemapping in QGIS. I have built virtual raster fields to load these in one go but I'm looking to store them within my PostgreSQL database to share with other users.

Does anyone know whether this is possible?

Comment: did you read the docs on PostGIS [raster support](https://postgis.net/docs/using_raster_dataman.html) and [function reference](https://postgis.net/docs/RT_reference.html)?

Comment: I'm a little out my depth with this sort of thing so was crossing my fingers for an easy QGIS import! Thanks for the response and i'll spend some time working through these documents.

Comment: It's probably a good idea to read some tutorials and browse for examples of actual use case scenarios. PostGIS' analytic capabilities are mighty, but is not the most straight forward environment to work with raster data, and it's usually not the most performant backend to serve it. The plain answer to your question is probably: use `raster2pgsql` to import all supported formats.